# How to limit focus to a Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

I Have a `Page` Containing some controls, this page will be loaded into a `ContentControl` in a `Window`.

Now, **How can i limit the focus cycle in my `Page`?** I don't want to pass the focus to out of `Page` after pressing TAB in last item of my page.

As a brief, **How Can I determine the next focus control and change it**

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: Ah, what a little question with a HUGE answer.
as examples:
1. Setting `Focusable` to false for all other controls except the `Page`, but then it's not focused on the `Page` itself. because it's contained in Window.
2. Dynamically changing `TabIndex` for all other controls out of the `Page`. It doesn't work because TabIndex has a value anyway!
3. so more, but i have no fluent english to describe them.

Comment: I can complete my question by asking this:

How can i determine next control to focus in code behind?

Comment: Hamed, not everybody will read the question comments, so if you are providing information about your question, please add them into your question so that everybody will see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always difficult to fully understand what a question author wants when they don't bother to provide you with more than a few hastily typed lines. However, as far as I understand your problem, it seems that you have some problem with focusing in your WPF Application.

The first thing to do is to direct you to the [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, where you can find out about the different focus types used in WPF. In particular, please pay attention to the *Navigating Focus Programmatically* section which discusses the [`TraversalRequest` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.traversalrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) that can help developers to move focus programmatically.

You should also pay careful attention to the *KeyboardNavigation* section that discusses the [`KeyboardNavigation` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx). This class contains some properties that enable you to define how the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key works in various scenarios, so this may be what you're after. It is used like this (from the last linked page on MSDN):

```
KeyboardNavigation.SetTabNavigation(navigationMenu, KeyboardNavigationMode.Cycle);
```

For future reference, you will get quicker and more accurate answers if you provide clear questions that include *all of your requirements* at the time of posting.

Comment: I can say a real THANKS!!! that's what I was looking for.
maybe if I wrote "Cycle" it was easy to answer. however really thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the FocusLost event - you might possibly be able to just refocus the page control with an event handler.

```
private void Page_LostFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((UIElement)sender).Focus();
    }
```